# Can't import pty module even though it's installed

Tags: python, import, module, pty

I have Python 2.7 installed on OpenSUSE. I'm using the `pty` module to spawn some ptys:

```
import pty
```

But Python can't seem to find it.

```
ImportError: No module named pty
```

Running `help('modules')` in the interpreter shows that `pty` is installed.

Comment: When you type `import pty` into the interpreter, does the traceback end right after `<stdin>`?

Comment: @Series8217 Typing `import pty` right in the interpreter (not from my IDE), simply gives me a new line `>>>`

Comment: Then the problem is likely with your IDE not setting up `sys.path` correctly.

Comment: If you just see a new line, that means it imported successfully. @Thomas K is correct, whatever you're running your code in is not set up the same way as the interpreter. Probably a path problem.

Comment: Odd, I'm using Netbeans. I've found `pty.py` in `/usr/lib64/python2.7` so I'll try adding that to the path and trying again.

Comment: @ThomasK yup that was it, wanna post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

The problem is likely that your IDE is not setting up `sys.path` correctly. Find where `pty` is imported from, and make sure that's on your PYTHONPATH in your IDE's settings.